# How to query a thread in SQL

Tags: sql, twitter

Threads on Twitter consist of tweets connected to each other in a chain where a tweet is pointed to from another tweet by its id. E.g

```
id   text            in_reply_to_status_id
------------------------------------------
1    Hello world     null
2    Hello Twitter   1
3    Hello TL        2
```

Is it possible to fetch a thread with one SQL query? If no, how does Twitter do it? Or do they store tweets differently from how they're retrieved from their API?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the database you use you could use a `CONNECT BY` clause to automatically unwrap the recursive hierarchy of these tweets.

How Twitter does it it's a different question, to provide quickly data to users, Twitter doesn't serve them from SQL databases, but from NoSQL caches, like Redis (and its variants) and Twemcache. You can start reading about this from the article [The Infrastructure Behind Twitter: Scale](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/infrastructure/2017/the-infrastructure-behind-twitter-scale.html), the cache section is the one you are looking for.

It is for sure a very interesting topic, but also very wide, trying to understand how Twitter works it's a good starting point. This is true also for me, to be honest I am not an expert of these technologies and your question lead me to a few things I want to read, so thanks for asking.